# How to apply a program to a column in a text in bash / awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text that contains something like this:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
text1.1 text1.2 text1.3 text1.4
text2.2 text2.2 text2.3 text3.4
```

I want to execute a program that transforms all the text in column 2 to a new text.
The program takes stdin and returns stdout, so it is called like this: echo `"text-to-transform" | myprogram`, and returns `"transformed-text"` to stdout.

What would be the easiest way to apply myprogram to the column2 and display the output in bash ?

The output would look something like this

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
text1.1 transformed-text1.2 text1.3 text1.4
text2.2 transformed-text2.2 text2.3 text3.4
```

I'm guessing awk is the way, but I don't know enough about it.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, probably awk is the way. But where do you have the input text? A file? Are you going to write the text it with line breaks and pipe it as you show? (Please don't)

Comment: The input text is a file, yes. I don't understand your second question, some words might be missing from the sentence. Can you expand on what you don't recommend ?

Comment: You can do `blackbox > tmpfile; awk 'FNR > 1 && NF > 1 {getline prefix < "tmpfile"; $2=prefix$2}1' file`

Comment: So if blackbox is actually 'python blackbox.py', that would become: `python blackbox.py > tmpfile; awk 'FNR > 1 && NF > 1 {getline prefix < "tmpfile"; $2=prefix$2}1' file` ?

Comment: Also, I seem to understand that you assumed the python program just creates a string prefix, when in fact it changes the whole output. So it goes from input1 to output1. Can you please break down the different parts of that awk command so I understand what each mean ?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin feel free to edit your answer, instead of replying to my original question, so that I can mark it as the accepted answer when it solves my issue.

Comment: HagridV, you wrote `echo "text-to-transform" | myprogram`, so I would think you are using `text-to-transform` as a placeholder for a text you'll **echo** to `myprogram`. But since the input text is a file (and that answers my previous question), there is no good reason for echoing to `myprogram` if `myprogram` is a decent program. As you can see, that indeed aroused some confusion...

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { myprogram = "tr [:lower:] [:upper:]" }
NR>1 {
    cmd = "printf \047%s\n\047, \047" $2 "\047 | " myprogram
    if ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ) {
        $2 = line
    }
    close(cmd)
}
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
column1 column2 column3 column4
text1.1 TEXT1.2 text1.3 text1.4
text2.2 TEXT2.2 text2.3 text3.4
```

Replace `myprogram = "tr [:lower:] [:upper:]"` with `myprogram = "<whatever your real program is called>"`. You can even parametrize it if you like:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR>1 {
    cmd = "printf \047%s\n\047, \047" $col "\047 | " myprogram
    if ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ) {
        $col = line
    }
    close(cmd)
}
{ print }

$ awk -v myprogram='tr [:lower:] [:upper:]' -v col=2 -f tst.awk file
column1 column2 column3 column4
text1.1 TEXT1.2 text1.3 text1.4
text2.2 TEXT2.2 text2.3 text3.4

$ awk -v myprogram='wc -c' -v col=2 -f tst.awk file
column1 column2 column3 column4
text1.1        9 text1.3 text1.4
text2.2        9 text2.3 text3.4

$ awk -v myprogram="sed 's/x/X/' | tr 't' '#'" -v col=3 -f tst.awk file
column1 column2 column3 column4
text1.1 text1.2 #eX#1.3 text1.4
text2.2 text2.2 #eX#2.3 text3.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an ugly way, just using `sed` to do a simple transform to column 2:

```
paste <(cut -f1 -d' ' file) <(cut -f2 -d' ' file | sed 's/text/TEXT/') <(cut -f3,4 -d' ' file)
```

**Output**

```
text1.1 TEXT1.2 text1.3 text1.4
text2.2 TEXT2.2 text2.3 text3.4
```

It is essentially pasting 3 files together side-by-side, so read it as:

```
paste file1 file2 file3
```

where `file1` is what you get when you cut the first field from your input file, `file2` is what you get when you cut and transform the second field of your input file and `file3` is what you get when you cut fields 3 and 4 from your input file.

---

Or plain `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read c1 c2 rest ; do
     c2trans=$(echo "$c2" | ./transformer)
     echo "$c1 $c2trans $rest"
done < file
```

Comment: I didn't know about the paste command, it seems appropriate here, thanks. Probably awk is more suited when there are more tabs, but this will do for me.

Comment: Actually when I tried this, it does not seem to work. When you pipe cut to sed, sed receives the whole column, right ? My program does not handle multiple inputs (lines) to give multiple outputs. It's just one output for a given input. So maybe awk is a better alternative in the end ? Do you know how to make it work with awk, using getline as David suggested ?

Comment: It's late here. I'm pretty sure I can do it tomorrow, but if you add the `awk` tag to your question, you'll likely get an answer pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks. Please check back again tomorrow to see if someone has added an answer. In the meantime I added +1 to your answer. I also added the awk tag to my question.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` you can simply concatenate a prefix to the second field, e.g.

```
awk 'FNR > 1 && NF > 1 {$2="transformed-"$2}1' file
```

Which just checks that you have at least 2 fields in the line and then sets then concatenates the prefix `"transformed-"` to the second field in the line from the second line in the file until the end.

**Example Use/Output**

Using a simple *heredoc* to provide the input to `awk` you could do:

```
$ cat << eof | awk 'FNR > 1 && NF > 1 {$2="transformed-"$2}1'
> column1 column2 column3 column4
> text1.1 text1.2 text1.3 text1.4
> text2.2 text2.2 text2.3 text3.4
> eof
column1 column2 column3 column4
text1.1 transformed-text1.2 text1.3 text1.4
text2.2 transformed-text2.2 text2.3 text3.4
```

Comment: I took "transformed-" as an example but actually my program is more complicated than that. Is it possible to call an external program from awk ?

Comment: Yes, there is a system command, or you can write to a temporary file from your external program and then use `getline` in awk to read the data (either from `stdin` or a file)

Comment: Can you give me a little more detail on what program is producing data you need to prefix with the second field? How are you generating the data that needs to be included? That would help -- otherwise there are too many possibilities to cover them all.

Comment: I marked the other answer as my accepted answer, as 'paste' seems appropriate in my case. But thanks for your answer which also seems interesting and perhaps more suited when there are more than just 3 columns. I would still be interested in knowing how that would work with awk.

Comment: The program is black box that takes an input and does some complicated stuff that can't be reproduced in bash (over 1000 of code in python) and returns an output.

Comment: Sure, just pipe the black-box to `awk` and use `getline` to read the program input along with your data file. [See Explicit Input with getline](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline.html#Getline) Okay. As you files grow, and you need a faster solution, look again at `awk`. It will be orders or magnitude faster than using 5 separate utilities in 5 separate processes piped together.

Comment: Can you please show the resulting command, assuming the program is called 'myprogram', reads from stdin, and writes to stdout ?